# How to use discrete cosine and discrete sine transforms in fftw

Tags: fourier-analysis, fftw

I work on fluid-related simulations. I have used FFT for fluid simulation. I want to use discrete cosine transform (DCT) and discrete sine transform (DST) to transform my velocity field to wavenumbers.

I am using `REDFT00` and `RODFT00` as DCT and DST respectively (so the inverse are themselves).

I understand that the normalization is $2(n-1)$ and $2(n+1)$, respectively.

for DCT and DST, I take

$u(x) = \cos(3x); n=64$

But when I invert it, values after $(n/2)+1$ are all incorrect.

What is the right way to do?

UPDATE: I was using an old library which was heavily modified(FFT worked fine though). I used the original library and everything works fine. But now I have difficulty in using the library for my purposes(Don't know how to take care of the wavenumbers) which I have posted as a separate question. So I guess I don't need the answer. It was a defective library.

Comment: What package are you using exactly? What do you mean with incorrect? To high, to low, NaN?

Comment: I am using P3DFFT LIBRARY. The values of the inverted matrix after x=(n/2)+1 are exactly 2(n-1) and 2(n+1) times smaller than the original one for dct and dst respectively.

Comment: If I multiply 2(n-1) and 2(n+1) to the values of the original matrix (for x>(n/2)+1)before transforming I get what I want but it is not the original matrix

Comment: I was using a modified p3dfft library. I changed the library to the original one and it fixed it.